# cv2_imshow() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I am getting the following error on Google Colab. How can I solve this?

> error: cv2_imshow() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
import cv2 import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img = cv2.imread('aaa.jpg')
layer = img.copy() 
gp={layer}
for i in range(6): 
layer=cv2.pyrDown(layer)
gp.append(layer)
cv2_imshow(str(i),layer)
cv2_imshow("original image",img)
cv2waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cv2_imshow does not accept title, as it is displaying it in the same notebook. Hence, you should use cv2_imshow(layer) instead of cv2_imshow(str(i),layer). Moreover, you can print(i) before the cv2_imshow(layer) to distinguish one output from another.
Good luck!